# How do I extract a specific match from Regex Extractor - Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

So I got this response from the expression highlighted, but I need to get the last result the one in "Match [ 5 ]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkwO1.png)  "

[image: Result]

I'm using this config, is this correct?

[image: Config]

I've seen several examples online but they all use the same config, how can I get the one I'm asking for?

Thanks in advance

I've tried switching them and putting 5 in both fields, but I keep getting the Match [one][one] every time

Comment: To match the last occurrence just add `.*` at the start of the regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I do that it just gives me extra values on the response

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 matches you will have the special [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `form_build_id_matchNr` with the value of `5` from where you can extract the last match so you can refer the last match using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) as:

```
${__V(form_build_id_${form_build_id_matchNr},)}
```

In this case you will need to set "Match No" in the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to `-1`

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

---

In general [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), you might want to consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) and come up with the proper selector to match only the "interesting" value